# update with wix

Tags: wix

My task is to create an update installation pack wich delete some dlls and replace config files of installed program. And I have original installation Wix project source. I've read on several places on the internet about how to build update Wix project and I got some questions.

As I understood I have to use the same Product and UpgradeCode GUIDs in my update Wix project. So I have to delete unnecessary files and to add new. Can anybody tell me what is the preferred way to remove old files?

What information I must use from original installation Wix project? At the beginning I want to create my new one using Product and UpgradeCode GUIDs, but may be it possible to modify oroginal project for update purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Lesson 4 of WiX Tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/) and [Patching and Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579.aspx) chapter of Windows Installer documentation should answer most of your questions. I would also recommend you playing with small test project to understand how the things work before implementing this in live solution.

Comment: Thank you, Yan. If I simply need to add my new own and to override some existing files is it normal to make for my task an installation project with <Property Id=”REINSTALLMODE” Value="amus"/>?

Comment: The 'a' option means 'force files to be reinstalled, regardless of the checksum and version'. This might be what you need, but generally it is not. The user might modify a certain file to his needs, and he doesn't expect this file to be overwritten during upgrade. If you require this file to be overwritten with the new one (for instance, if some critical functionality depends on this), then I suppose it is acceptable. In this case warn the user to backup his customizations if there are any to prevent losing the data.